# How to configure virtual network adapters for Ubuntu Server on Virtual Box

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ubuntu-server

I have two network adapters on Virtual Box for Ubuntu Server.

- Adapter 1: internal network called `intent`
- Adapter 2: NAT

I want to configure them as follows:

- Static IP 192.168.10.101 for the internal network adapter, netmask 255.255.255.0
- DHCP IP for the NAT adapter

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the virtual box with your normal account and use `su` to get an admin account.

Then open `/etc/network/interfaces` in an editor.

To set up a static IP use

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.10.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Sadly I am not sure what you mean with *DHCP IP for the NAT adapter*

To setting up a simply DHCP IP for eth1 use add

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

to the file you just edited.

If you want this line to connect to the outside world with and actually do NATting then you will need to enable IP forwarding, load the MASQ module and set up some routing. If that is you goal then please clarify your post.

Answer (score -1):

To do so you will need to enter the following code and create a password (you will be prompted to enter it twice):

```
sudo passwd root
```

This will allow you to become the root user. Then enter:

```
su
```

Then use the vi editor with the following:

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

This will let you change the desired settings, just hit <kbd>i</kbd> to edit. When finished, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then type `:x` to save the changes.